# Error with Opencart

Tags: paypal, opencart

I installed the module chekout Express OpenCart 2.1.0.1 for my eshop www.lecoccolekids.com/eshop
I created the API of my business account, I created a sandbox account and I connected my business account for my sandbox account.
When I went to do a test purchase on my website everything goes well and the system sends me back to the order page made, but if I go to check in Opencart System-> Tool-> ErrorLog returns error. In http://www.famarinu.com/log.rtf link you can download the file where log.rtf control the type of error.

What should I do?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your linked document seems to contain the debug logs of the transaction and no errors.

It contains the SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment API requests that your integration is sending and the response from PayPal.

It's also showing that an IPN was received for the transaction and PayPal responded with VERIFIED when your integration POSTed back for verification.

If you are worried about the "Transaction exists" line, that seems to be an intended log line from your PayPal module, and not an error, as seen here:

https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=115661

Comment: So, these are not errors, and to every transaction that my system will write to me all this debug logs?

Comment: That seems to be the case.

The logs you attached don't show any error from PayPal, but rather the intended API and IPN messages upon a successful transaction.